# How to send email with Mailgun using C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, mailgun

I'm using this [simple ArduinoHttpClient example code](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api) to send a sample POST request from my [Arduino Uno Wifi Rev 2](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-uno-wifi-rev2) to a publicly accessible URL. It works. I get a legit response.

But now, I want to send a HTTP request from my Arduino code that mimics this curl call to send an email [via MailGun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMxx1.png):

```
curl \
--request POST \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--user 'api:XXX-my-API-key-obtained-from-mailgun-website-XXX' \
--data-urlencode from='Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox7d1aaf2f157f42d8844b1ac4c38a0ef7.mailgun.org>' \
--data-urlencode to='Me <myemail@gmail.com>' \
--data-urlencode subject='Hello World1' \
--data-urlencode text='Hello World2' \
"https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox7d1aaf2f157f42d8844b1ac4c38a0ef7.mailgun.org/messages"
```

How can I do it? When I intercepted this curl call with a proxy, I see that it is sending these bytes:

```
POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox7d1aaf2f157f42d8844b1ac4c38a0ef7.mailgun.org/messages HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mailgun.net
Authorization: Basic YYY-basic-auth-token-YYY
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 183
from=Mailgun%20Sandbox%20%3Cpostmaster%40sandbox7d1aaf2f157f42d8844b1ac4c38a0ef7.mailgun.org%3E&to=Me%20%3Cmyemail%40gmail.com%3E&subject=Hello%20World1&text=Hello%20World2
```

It's difficult to recreate that in C++. How is that `Authorization` token determined? There must be an idiomatic/well-known way to do this.

The [Mailgun](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api) website lists examples snippets from several languages, but [not C/C++](https://twitter.com/Mail_Gun/status/1249966058284466176).

[image]

Comment: The [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-intro.html#authentication) tells you what should go in the Authorization header. As for your main question, the arguments you give to `curl` almost map directly to settings in `libcurl`.

Answer (score 0):

kindly check this documentation [documentation on how to send mail using mailgun](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#how-to-start-sending-email)and see if it helps